# Fixed Point in Calculus

Tags: calculus

I have been working on the problem below and I am now at a point where I am stuck. I know I have to have a proof, but I am not $100\text{%}$ confident on the last part of the problem (absolute value of the derivative). When I started on this problem, I am pretty confident have to use the IVT to show the fixed point. Any guidance will be great.

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$.  If there exists a constant $b < 1$ such that $|f'(x)|<b$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $f$ has a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$.  Be sure to consider and use previous homework results.

[image]
I was thinking this is the assignment questions and answers which correspond to this question.

Comment: The instructions are to “consider and use previous homework results.”  That means the ideal answer is going to build on your previous work.  Which of those results do you think are relevant?

Comment: I attached the previous problems which were useful I flt in my working on this problem.

Comment: OK, so your exercise is to prove that a function with a certain property has a fixed point, and a previous exercise shows that one kind of function has a fixed point.  If you could show that the function in the problem is contractive, you would be done.  Do you see why?

Comment: Yes. It is because if a function is contractive there exists a fixed point.

Comment: Good, so now your exercise is to show: *If $f$ is differentiable and there exists $b<1$ such that $|f'(x)| < b$ for all $x$, then $f$ is contractive.*

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** draw the line $y=1 \cdot x$. wlog suppose that $f(0)>0$. Notice that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, you need $f(x)>x$. Derive a contradiction, by the fact that $f(x) < f(0)+bx$, and that there exists some $x_0$ so that $f(0)+bx_0=x_0$ (nonparallel lines intersect!) [in this case, in the first quadrant]. Yes, you are going to need the continuity condition.

**Edit:** Since you added some additional information, I'll give an alternative method.

Show that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and has bounded derivate, s.t $|f^{\prime}(x)| \leq b<1$, we can show that it is contractive. Suppose wlog that $x>y$. Then

$$|f(x)-f(y)| <|f(y)+b(x-y)-f(y)|=b|x-y|.$$

Then $f$ is contraction map. Can you take it from here?